# Cassandra-jdbc and glassfish

Tags: cassandra, glassfish-3

I am trying to setup a jdbc pool in Glassfish 3 using the latest cassandra-jdbc driver.  I have copied all of the dependency jars to the lib directory of my domain, but when I try to save the pool I get the following error:

Ping Connection Pool failed for api_cassandra. Error instantiating class : org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.

The log doesn't give me anything more than this.  I have been able to use the jdbc driver to connect using dbvis and through code, but I'm guessing I don't have something setup correctly in glassfish.  Has anyone else been able to setup a cassandra pool in glassfish?  I'm fairly new to glassfish so any setup information would be extremely helpful.

One thing to add, for normal datapools the constructor does not take any arguments, but for the cassandra-jdbc driver there is not an empty constructor, you have to pass in arguments, which I believe is why the instantiation is failing.  So I think the real question is how do you pass constructor arguments through glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that slf4j wasn't loading correctly because it depends on log4j.jar. Add it in classpath, and make sure that all jars is there:

- apache-cassandra-{version}.jar
- apache-cassandra-clientutil-{version}.jar
- apache-cassandra-thrift-{version}.jar
- cassandra-jdbc-{version}.jar
- commons-lang-{version}.jar
- guava-{version}.jar
- libthrift-{version}.jar
- log4j-{version}.jar
- slf4j-api-{version}.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-{version}.jar